# ASP VBScript Redim Preserve Type mismatch - Scope of variable definition

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a classic ASP page, which includes a server side in the  section

```
<!--#include file="../includes/DataTransferFunctions.asp"-->
```

Within this function, I have the following at the top of the library file,

```
  Dim wsDataToXferArray()
```

and then, within one of the functions in the library, it does

```
 redim preserve wsDataToXferArray(3,pSub).
```

This doesn't work as I get a type mismatch on the redim statement.  However, if I have the Dim statement at the top of the main ASP instead of at the top of the include library it works.

I need to be able to declare the variable in a global scope so that is it available to more than one function within the library, but have it so that it is defined within the library code so that it is self-contained.  I feel as though I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Here are cut-down versions which show the problem.  I have included the main ASP and the relevant library which shows the location of the '2 Dim' statements.

Thanks.

```
<%@ language = vbscript %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%

Response.Buffer = true
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
Response.CodePage = 1252
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"

Dim wsResult,wsDatabase
Dim wsSubX
'
'Dim wsDataToXferArray()

subRoutine()
'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub subRoutine
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    wsSubX  = 0
'
    if wsResult = "" then wsResult  = fncEnableSetAndCreateDataTransfer(wsDatabase,"LK-PART","abc","A",wsSubX)              :   wsSubX  = wsSubX + 1

End Sub

%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<%
SubIncludeOtherStyleSheets
SubIncludeJs
%>

<!--Include file containing functions to convert dates and to get sales order status description -->
<!--#include file="../includes/date_convert.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/KHDataTransferFunctions.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/IncludeStyleSheets.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/IncludeJs.asp"-->

</head>

<body>

<form action="KHPartMaintenance.asp" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >

<table class="tableForm Center Font7pt" width="1000">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Part Maintenance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="submit1" name="submit1" id="btnList" value="Get Part" onclick="javascript:return fncFormOnSubmit('Get');" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the KHDataTransferFunctions.asp library.

```
<%
Dim wsDataToXferArray()

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function fncEnableSetAndCreateDataTransfer(pDatabase,pName,pValue,pDataType,pSub)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Dim wsPrefix    :   wsPrefix = left(pName,2)
'
    fncEnableSetAndCreateDataTransfer   = ""

    call subAddFieldToDataTransferArray(wsPrefix,pName,pValue,pDataType,pSub)

end function

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub subAddFieldToDataTransferArray(pPrefix,pName,pValue,pDataType,pSub)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' Build the array of the fields for each 'transaction'.
'
    redim preserve wsDataToXferArray(3,pSub)

    wsDataToXferArray(0,pSub)   = pPrefix
    wsDataToXferArray(1,pSub)   = pName
    wsDataToXferArray(2,pSub)   = pValue
    wsDataToXferArray(3,pSub)   = pDataType
'   
End Sub

%>
```

I've resolved the problem.  It was caused by the position of the include files within the ASP page.

Here's the revised code (well, part of it ....).

```
<%@ language = vbscript %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%

Response.Buffer = true
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
Response.CodePage = 1252
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"
%>
<!--Include file containing functions to convert dates and to get sales order status description -->
<!--#include file="../includes/date_convert.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/KHDataTransferFunctions.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/IncludeStyleSheets.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../includes/IncludeJs.asp"-->
    <%
Dim wsResult,wsDatabase
Dim wsSubX
'
'Dim wsDataToXferArray()

subRoutine()
'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub subRoutine
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    wsSubX  = 0
'
    if wsResult = "" then wsResult  = fncEnableSetAndCreateDataTransfer(wsDatabase,"LK-PART","abc","A",wsSubX)              :   wsSubX  = wsSubX + 1

End Sub

%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<%
SubIncludeOtherStyleSheets
SubIncludeJs
%>
```

Comment: can you show a bit of code, i tried to test your setup and am not getting any errors ..

Comment: Can you prove that pSub is decent in case of type mismatch error?

Comment: wsSubX  = 0
you are trying to redim array(3,0)

Comment: That's not a problem.  Arrays are zero based, so (3,0) is 4 elements by 1 element.  Also, the code works if the Dim statement in in the main code and not in the library.  As you can see, it's commented out in the main ASP code, but if I re-instate and comment out the library Dim, then it works.

Comment: You might want to add your resolution as your own answer. I just wanted to give you the advice to place your include files at the top of your page, but then noted that you solved it yourself.

Comment: Thansk.  I don't know how to flag it as an answer.  I've flagged for moderation intervention to close.  Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Keith click on the "Answer Your Question" button that appears below and write what you did to resolve this problem then accept your own answer. As a side note when replying to comment please use `@` like I did now, it will notify the other user you have replied to his/her comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by the location of the server side include files.  These need to be before the main ASP code gets executed, so that any global variables are declared early enough.

See the block with the modified code in the original post for the solution.